# htaccess to check if query string exist otherwise use previous rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to convert this url

http://127.0.0.1/kurumsal/index.php?sayfa=referans&page=2

to this

http://127.0.0.1/kurumsal/index/sayfa/referans/page/2/

but not every page has pagination which refers to page=2 query string. i want to just use first part of query string if 'page' query string do not exist.

So it would be http://127.0.0.1/kurumsal/index/sayfa/referans/ without pagination query string.

followed some tutorials but no luck, here is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)page=($|&)
RewriteRule ^sayfa/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /kurumsal/index.php?sayfa=$1&page=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^sayfa/([^/]*)/$ /kurumsal/index.php?sayfa=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Pls specify where the htaccess file is placed?

Comment: @WEBDEVPR project root folder which is /kurumsal/

Answer (score 1):

Try using this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^kurumsal/index/sayfa/([^/]*)/page/([^/]*)$ /kurumsal/index.php?sayfa=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in `root/.htaccess`  :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /kurumsal/index\.php\?sayfa=([^\&]+)(?:&page=)?(.*?)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /kurumsal/index/sayfa/%1/%2? [L,R]
RewriteRule ^(?:kurumsal/)?index/sayfa/([^/]+)/?(.*?)/?$ /kurumsal/index.php?sayfa=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /kurumsal/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^index/sayfa/([^/]*)/page/([^/]*)/$ /kurumsal/index.php?sayfa=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^index/sayfa/([^/]*)/$ /kurumsal/index.php?sayfa=$1 [L]
```